# Whenever I Put the payment page on my app, it goes blank on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, element

I'm doing an e-commerce app in which you rent tuxedos but when I go to the payments page it goes blank. It happened when I installed Stripe API on my app and it became buggy in the specific page. In this version of React, I tried to put  on the payment page but it goes blank. Can you guys help me solve this problem please?

Here's my code on App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header.js';
import Home from './Home.js';
import Checkout from './Checkout.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Login';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import Payment from './Payment';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const promise = loadStripe('some stripe api here');

function App() {
  const [{}, dispatch] =useStateValue();
  useEffect(() => {
    //Only run once the app component logs
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      console.log('User is signed in', authUser)
      if (authUser) {
        dispatch({
          type:'SET_USER',
          user: authUser
        })
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type:'SET_USER',
          user: null
        })
      }
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    //BEM
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={[<Login />]}/>
          <Route path="/checkout" element={[<Header />, <Checkout />]}/>
          <Route path="/payment" element={[<Header />, <Elements stripe={promise} />, <Payment />]}/>
          <Route path="/" element={[<Header />, <Home />]}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now here's my code on the Payment page (Payment.js):

```
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import CheckoutProduct from './CheckoutProduct';
import './Payment.css';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import { getCartTotal } from './reducer';
import axios from 'axios';

function Payment() {
    const [{cart, user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
    const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(""); 
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getClientSecret = async() => {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: `/payments/create?total=${getCartTotal(cart) * 100}`
            });
            setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
        }
        getClientSecret();
    }, [cart])

    const handleSubmit = async(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setProcessing(true);
        const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method : {
                card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
            }
        }).then(({paymentIntent}) => {
            setSucceeded(true);
            setError(null)
            setProcessing(false)
            navigate('/orders', {replace:true});
        })
    }
    const handleChange = event => {
        setDisabled(event.empty);
        setError(event.error ? event.error.message : '');
        
    }
  return (
    <div className='payment'>
        <div className='payment_container'>
            <h1> Checkout (<Link to='/checkout'> {cart?.length} items </Link>) </h1>
            {/* Payment section - Delivery address */}
            <div className='payment_section'>
                <div className='payment_title'>
                    <h3> Delivery Address </h3>
                </div>
                <div className='payment_address'>
                    <p> {user?.email} </p>
                    <p> 123 Elvis Lane </p>
                    <p> Austin, Texas </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* Payment section - Review items */}
            <div className='payment_section'>
                <div className='payment_title'>
                    <h3> Review items and delivery </h3>
                    <div className='payment_items'>
                        {cart.map(item => (
                            <CheckoutProduct 
                                id = {item.id}
                                title = {item.title}
                                image = {item.image}
                                price = {item.price}
                                rating = {item.rating}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* Payment section - Payment method */}
            <div className='payment_section'>
                <div className='payment_title'>
                    <h3> Payment Method </h3>
                    <div className='payment_details'>
                        {/* Stripe API */}
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <CardElement onChange={handleChange} />
                            <div className='payment_priceContainer'>
                                <CurrencyFormat 
                                    renderText={(value) => (
                                        <>
                                            <h3> Order Total: {value} </h3>
                                        </>
                                    )}
                                    decimalScale={2}
                                    value= {getCartTotal(cart)}
                                    displayType={"text"}
                                    thousandSeparator={true}
                                    prefix={"$"}
                                />
                                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                                    <span> {processing ? <p> Processing </p> : "Buy Now"} </span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Payment
```

Is this an error on App.js or is it in Payment.js? The page should display the info and the payment form.

Edit: I found out it was in the Payment.js code somewhere around here:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const stripe = useStripe();
const elements = useElements();

const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(""); 
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    const getClientSecret = async() => {
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `/payments/create?total=${getCartTotal(cart) * 100}`
        });
        setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
    }
    getClientSecret();
}, [cart])

const handleSubmit = async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);
    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method : {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then(({paymentIntent}) => {
        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null)
        setProcessing(false)
        navigate('/orders', {replace:true});
    })
}
const handleChange = event => {
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : '');
```

Can you guys help me fix this please? It seems that in this section is where the error is occurring.

Edit 2:
Here's of how it should look like: [image: How it should look like]

Here's what actually happens:

[image: Here's what happens]

Edit 3: Here's what the console gives me as an error, maymbe it is in the elements tag that causes the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add details about any errors you're seeing in the web browser's dev tools under the console and network tabs?

Comment: @JustinMichael done! Hope you can solve it.

Comment: That doesn't show the error detail in the console or network tabs. You need to open your browser's developer tools: https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/use-the-developer-tools-in-the-develop-menu-sfri20948/mac

Comment: @JustinMichael I see that the Elements tag is causing the problem, but I'm not sure on how to solve it. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to [wrap your checkout page in an Elements provider](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#add-and-configure-the-elements-provider-to-your-payment-page):

> To use the Payment Element component, wrap your checkout page component in an [Elements provider](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider). Call `loadStripe` with your publishable key, and pass the returned `Promise` to the `Elements` provider. Also pass the [client secret](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret) from the previous step as `options` to the `Elements` provider.

The sample code Stripe provides shows how to properly structure your app:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

import CheckoutForm from './CheckoutForm';

// Make sure to call `loadStripe` outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_123');

function App() {
  const options = {
    // passing the client secret obtained in step 2
    clientSecret: '{{CLIENT_SECRET}}',
    // Fully customizable with appearance API.
    appearance: {/*...*/},
  };

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
      <CheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import {PaymentElement} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const CheckoutForm = () => {
  return (
    <form>
      <PaymentElement />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CheckoutForm;
```

Comment: How do I do that on the current React version? It is React 6, it seems that it requires an older version to do so.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  [The current version of React is 18, not 6.](https://reactjs.org/versions/). Can you explain in more detail exactly what issue you're having and tell us the specific version of React (and other relevant packages) you're using?